# Usage of XVM in ink! smart contract

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call, cross-chain

Since the early stages of Polkadot development, I've been intrigued by the promise of cross-chain smart contract communication. I've successfully built simple but a fully functioning decentralized exchange, but now I'm searching for interfaces or traits that would allow me to enable cross-chain calls. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the required information (in my imagination as it could work in practice).

To elaborate, I want to deploy my smart contract on Astar and Shiden parachains and facilitate cross-chain swaps. I believe I need specific interfaces to implement this functionality, but my search has been fruitless so far. With that in mind, my question is: How can I achieve cross-chain calls in ink!?

Please correct me if my thinking is flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way at the moment to do ink! cross-chain contract.
Astar & Parity are actively working on this.
In the meantime this is Astar [roadmap](https://forum.astar.network/t/runtime-interface-contracts-goodbye-chain-extensions-welcome-call-runtime/4795/2) regarding ink! XCM: